# Office 2010: Use license for multiple OS on same machine

Tags: linux, microsoft-office, license

I have purchased an Office 2010 License Key for Windows a while ago. I went for the normal edition, that is to say not Enterprise or anything like that.

Now I have installed Linux on my machine as well (dual boot) and want to install Office 2010 using playonlinux there aswell.

Can I reuse the license key that I used for the Windows installation? I should note that I don't want to uninstall it on Windows but have it installed twice.

Thanks for your answers

Tony

Comment: As you positive it will even work?

Comment: Assuming office will install on linux, the license key may not activate. Office activation goes to MS server, so they will have a record that you have already installed and activated office.